# Apache beam : groupbykey with multiple key of custom datatype

Tags: apache-beam

I am creating a pipeline in apache beam where i need to groupbykey with two keys.
I have below data set 
Trasnasctions.txt

```
101,Credit,100,21-09-2017
101,Dedit,200,22-09-2017
101,Credit,300,23-09-2017
102,Credit,500,26-09-2017
102,Debit,600,27-09-2017
```

need to group the input data with Account_ID and transaction type.
With 1 key its working fine.

```java
p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new filterAccountIdAmount()))
    .apply(GroupByKey.<String, Long>create())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new addAmounts()))
```

for two keys i have created a class AggregateFieldsAccount and pass the type class in groupbykey as below.

```java
p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new filterAccountIdAmount()))
    .apply(GroupByKey.<AggregateFieldsAccount, Long> create())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new addAmounts()))
    .apply(MapElements.via(new FormatAsTextFn()))
```

Getting below error.

> No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
>     Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Cannot provide coder for parameterized type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV: Unable to provide a Coder for org.apache.beam.examples.Demo_Direct$AggregateFieldsAccount.
>     Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
>     See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
>     Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:257)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifying(PCollection.java:106)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.finishSpecifyingInput(TransformHierarchy.java:190)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:524)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:460)
>           at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:284)
>           at org.apache.beam.examples.Demo_Direct.main(Demo_Direct.java:155)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a coder for `AggregateFieldsAccount`. You can find more details [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#specifying-coders).